# How to calculate adjusted HR?

Tags: survival, cox-model

What is the difference between crude HR and adjusted HR in Cox regression? How do we calculate adjusted HR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crude HR refers to the HR estimate from a cox regression model including only your variable of interest as predictor.
Adjusted HR usually refers to the estimated HR of that variable where other covariates are also included in the cox regression model.

Comment: SO, "CRUDE HR" WE GET IN UNIVARIATE ANALYSIS AND "ADJUSTED HR" - IN MULTIVARIATE?

Comment: Right, but it's not multivariate, it's multivariable. Multivariate refers to multiple response variables.

Comment: Great Thanks for explanation and useful correction!